# Get imported module objects

Tags: python, inheritance, module

Lets say we have a main program which follows:

```
class Bob():
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hi, I'm", self.__class__.__name__

import usesBob
```

Where usesBob is

```
Bob = get_bob_from_main()
class Dave(Bob): pass
Dave()
Bob()
```

Dave should print "Hi, I'm Dave" and
Bob should print "Hi, I'm Bob"

Obviously I won't be using this in production code, I just want to know if it is possible and if so, how.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I can't get Bob from usesBob

Comment: It's not clear what your expectation is here; you can do `from __main__ import Bob` here, for example, which would import the class from the current running script.

Comment: That is what I want. It now works, happy to accept answer if posted as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import from the main script by importing from `__main__`:

```
from __main__ import Bob

class Dave(Bob): pass
Dave()
Bob()
```